# Set global culture for DateTimeOffset Format etc on .Net Core Console App

Tags: c#, .net

How can I set *global culture* for `DateTimeOffset` Format etc on .Net Core Console App?
My problem is that my pc is using a *nordic culture* which formats datetimeoffset like `"03.07.2019"` when it should format it like `03-07-2019` or `2019-07-01`.

How can I fix this? My program is running async tasks.

Because the `DateTimeOffset` is a `ToString();` so I have a hard way to convert the string while keeping it as a string type.

Comment: First of all, post your code. Did you set the culture you want anywhere? If you *don't* the default is to use the user's locale. Culture should flow across async calls. Finally, the compiler probably emits a localization warning already saying you should pass the culture explicitly instead of depending on the ambient culture

Comment: Another, perhaps better option is to specify the format you want when you need it. `YYYY-MM-DD` isn't used by any country so it's probably not used by any culture. It's a format typically used by programs. Instead of creating a custom culture you should probably [specify that format explicitly when needed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_ToString_System_String_), with a format specifier, eg `myTime.ToString("u")` or `myTime.ToString("s")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifing `DateTimeFormat`, e.g.

```
  CultureInfo modified = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

  // Same as current culture, except for Date Pattern: we want Nordic order
  modified.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";

  // Assign as a "Global" culture
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = modified;
```

Demo:

```
  Console.Write(DateTimeOffset.Now().ToString());
```

Outcome:

```
  2019-07-03 10:17:55 +03:00
```